# problems with code coverage on sonarqube and azure devops with Angular 6

Tags: typescript, sonarqube, azure-devops, code-coverage, lcov

Hi all and thanks in advance for reading this.

I have some problems with the manual execution of unit testing on local and also for running these ones on azure devops and the reporting of the results on sonarqube.

When I run `ng test` I get these errors:

```
Chrome 71.0.3578 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined\nat http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:122:12\n\nTypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined\n    at setTransitionEndSupport (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:122:12)\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:200:5\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:202:4\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:9:4\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:10:2",
    "str": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined\nat http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:122:12\n\nTypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined\n    at setTransitionEndSupport (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:122:12)\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:200:5\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:202:4\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:9:4\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:10:2"
  }

Chrome 71.0.3578 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined\nat http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:122:12\n\nTypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined\n    at setTransitionEndSupport (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:122:12)\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:200:5\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:202:4\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:9:4\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:10:2",
    "str": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined\nat http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:122:12\n\nTypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined\n    at setTransitionEndSupport (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:122:12)\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:200:5\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:202:4\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:9:4\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.js:10:2"
```

I cannot see the execution of these test on the terminal, but get the browser window for debugging.

You can find package.json and karma.conf.js below:

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test --code-coverage --watch=false",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.4",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.4",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-markdown": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.11.3",
    "@angular/cli": "6.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.1.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.7.2"
  },
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    files: [
      { pattern: 'src/**/*.ts' }
    ],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcov', 'cobertura' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: 'coverage',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html', subdir: 'report-html' },
        { type: 'cobertura', subdir: 'cobertura-html' },
        { type: 'lcov', subdir: 'coverage' }
      ]
  },
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul', 'junit', 'coverage'],
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: '',
      outputFile: 'test.xml',
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Also regarding with this problem, I'm also getting the lcov.info file empty, so I'm completely lost on this way.

Is there a bug between versions or something like that? Or I'm doing something bad?

Thanks!

**EDIT: FIRST PROBLEM SOLVED**

It was a problem in the bootstrap.js. I just install jquery library and put in my angular.json file the reference to jquery before the bootstrap one.

**angular.json**

```
"test": {
     "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
     "options": {
       "main": "src/test.ts",
       "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
       "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
       "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
       "scripts": [
         "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", //this one
         "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
       ],
```

I still have the problem with the file I have to generate for the code coverage.

I tried, karma-coverage, karma-typescript, karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter and I'm having problems and errors with all of them. I'm going to share my tsconfig.json just in case.

**tsconfig.json**

```
    {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: In what way is this question SonarQube related?

Comment: Because sonarqube needs a lcov.info file to read the code coverage. And the lcov.info file generated is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution executing on npm console:

```
npm test
```

and with the configuration of `--code-coverage` in `package.json` all the problems are solved.